# Using CHACHA20 Draft on openssl 1.1.0

Tags: openssl

I want to use CHACHA20 Draft on openssl 1.1.0, but openssl 1.1.0 only supports standard version.
However, CHACHA20 Draft is required on Android browser.

So can I use CHACHA20 Draft on openssl 1.1.0? Or what else can I try?

Comment: *"Or what else can I try"* - You might try upgrading the Security Provider. The process is in place to fix vulnerabilities, but it may also work for upgrades like this since it affects interoperability. Also see [Updating Your Security Provider to Protect Against SSL Exploits](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-gms-provider.html). And for completeness, I don't know if it will work. Its only a suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

When using nginx as the webserver, Cloudflare released a patch on Github (intentionally for OpenSSL stable branch 1.0.2j), that enables both the draft and standard version of this cipher. You can try it out, maybe it works for OpenSSL-1.1.0, too.

[Patch here](https://github.com/cloudflare/sslconfig/blob/master/patches/openssl__chacha20_poly1305_draft_and_rfc_ossl102j.patch).

You can use it by switching into the directory of the nginx-sourcecode and then type:

`patch -p1 < openssl__chacha20_poly1305_draft_and_rfc_ossl102j.patch`